# How can I convert *.flv file to *.ts file using FFmpeg on command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

How can I convert *.flv file to *.ts file using FFmpeg on command line? Is there any document about this?

Best Regards,
Defonds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i abc.flv abc.ts` 
This will generate .ts with mpeg2video and mp2 audio.
To generate with h264 video use

```
ffmpeg -i abc.flv -vcodec libx264 abc.ts
```

Answer (score 4):

if you do not want to encode,you can use this:"ffmpeg -i input.flv -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb output.ts"

Comment: That looks like an answer to the original question to me, as it will convert flv to ts as asked. It also gives useful information that this transformation can be done without re-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To get a .ts video you'd need to encode video with h264 and the best way to do that with ffmpeg is via libx264. If you want audio be sure to encode audio with aac. The command would look something like this

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac out.ts
```